# File reading from Amazon server, ruby on rails, no match route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm now developing Ruby on rails application with Heroku server and AWS. 
In the application, I have to read the text file. I tested locally and now put this file in AWS.

When I put the address of my file in AWS, the below error message pops up.

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ringleplus2015/my_file.txt):
```

When I copy and paste this address at Chrome, I can download file without an issue.

```
#file = File.open("./my_file.txt","r")  
file = File.open("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testbuckethoho/my_file.txt","r")
```

I allowed anybody to read this.

Also, in the html.rb file, I also put the link that users would be able to download pdf file from.
" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Case Download

But when I clicked it, it says " This webpage is not available." I look the address carefully and the ":" is gone between "https" and "//"

```
https//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testbuckethoho/What+Consumers+Want+from+Their+Displays+%7C+The+Applied+Materials+Blog.pdf
```

When I include ":" there, it works. But if I include ":" in my html file, it leads me to this error.

```
No route matches [GET] "/home/:/https:/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testbuckethoho/What+Consumers+Want+from+Their+Displays+%7C+The+Applied+Materials+Blog.pdf"
```

Would anybody help me figure out what is now causing this problem and handle it? :)

Comment: Can you how you get the address of your s3 file?

Comment: I upload my file into AWS. -> 1. create bucket -> 2. upload my file -> 3. click the property -> 4. There is a link -> 5. copy and paste ! This is the procedure!

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is looking for a local file named `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testbuckethoho/my_file.txt`. It doesn't know to make a request to a remote host.

There's a various approaches to solve this, the built-in one is [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).

Comment: I solved the text file reading with your suggestion. Thanks. However about the pdf file open, I don't know how to do this. Just the http:// become http// so that my web broswer can't access to it. Would you give me any thought? :)

Comment: This is not just about the case with the file stored in AWS. I also tested with any source with http:// but it suddenly becomes http//. :(