# Getting "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" while reading the CSV file from the AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have application which is deployed to Heroku. I have added functionality for uploading users thorough the CSV. For this I have provided CSV upload functionality (Used Paperclip gem).

Here is my code for reading the file and creating new user

```
def import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      row_hash = row.to_hash.values
      data = row_hash[0].split("\t")
      .
      .
      .
end
```

On the local it is working fine. But on the heroku it is giving me following error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://s3.amazonaws.com/..../..../sample_csv(2).csv
```

I referred following links 
[Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory) in amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220428/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-in-amazon-s3)

[File reading from Amazon server, ruby on rails, no match route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410951/file-reading-from-amazon-server-ruby-on-rails-no-match-route)

but didn't any success. For more debugging, I tried same url from my local rails console and it is giving me the same error.

```
2.2.2 :008 > cp = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/..../..../sample_csv(2).csv"
2.2.2 :008 > f = File.open(cp, "r")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://s3.amazonaws.com
```

Also tried open uri http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html.

I can download the same file from the browser.

Can any one let me know how to resolve this error. Is there any bucket permission issue (I have already provided open access for the bucket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

def import(file)
  CSV.new(open(file), :headers => :true).each do |row|  #First open the file using open
      row_hash = row.to_hash.values
      data = row_hash[0].split("\t")
      .
      .
      .
end
```

For more info you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005139/ruby-1-9-2-read-and-parse-a-remote-csv)