# Open CSV file in worker method not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, heroku, amazon-s3

I need a CSV stored on S3 to be read, and saved into a postgresql db on Heroku.

In development, this worked fine, but the files were saved locally and not

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, :headers => true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
    puts 'CSV is open'
    puts row
    if row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?)
    else
        @datum = Datum.new
        @datum.attributes = row.to_hash.reject{|k,v| !@datum.attributes.keys.member?(k.to_s) }
        @datum.user_id = current_user_id
        @datum.batch_id = batch_id
        @datum.save
    end
end
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146685/getting-errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen-while-reading-th), and added `require 'open-uri'` and `require 'csv'` to `/app/workers/batch_worker.rb`

Then I changed it to

```
 CSV.new(open(file), :headers => true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
      puts 'CSV is open'
      puts row
      if row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?)
      else
        @datum = Datum.new
        @datum.attributes = row.to_hash.reject{|k,v| !@datum.attributes.keys.member?(k.to_s) }
        @datum.user_id = current_user_id
        @datum.batch_id = batch_id
        @datum.save
      end
 end
```

The full method in batches_worker.rb:

```
 def perform(service_id, batch_id, current_user_id, file)
    batch = Batch.find(batch_id)

    CSV.new(open(file), :headers => true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
      puts 'CSV is open'
      puts row
      if row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?)
      else
        @datum = Datum.new
        @datum.attributes = row.to_hash.reject{|k,v| !@datum.attributes.keys.member?(k.to_s) }
        @datum.user_id = current_user_id
        @datum.batch_id = batch_id
        @datum.save
      end
    end

    if service_id.to_i === 3
        batch.progress = "Verify Email In Progress"
        batch.save
        verify_email(batch_id, current_user_id)
    elsif service_id.to_i === 5
        batch.progress = "Verify Phone In Progress"
        batch.save
        verify_active_phone(batch_id, current_user_id)
    elsif service_id.to_i === 1
        batch.progress = "Append Email In Progress"
        batch.save
        append_email(batch_id, current_user_id)
    elsif service_id.to_i === 4
        batch.progress = "Append Phone In Progress"
        batch.save
        append_phone(batch_id, current_user_id)
     elsif service_id.to_i === 2
        batch.progress = "Append Name In Progress"
        batch.save
        append_name_address(batch_id, current_user_id)
    end
end
```

My server logs. There are no errors, but it goes completely past the entire CSV section.

```
2018-01-30T01:24:37.112667+00:00 app[worker.2]: 4 TID-vco0s BatchWorker JID-b0a151240278a0063f608da7 INFO: start
2018-01-30T01:24:37.116144+00:00 app[worker.2]:   Batch Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "batches".* FROM "batches" WHERE "batches"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 55], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-01-30T01:24:37.116377+00:00 app[worker.2]: file is https://s3.amazonaws.com/example/example/csv_files/000/000/055/original/brick.csv
2018-01-30T01:24:37.147023+00:00 app[worker.2]:    (1.1ms)  BEGIN
2018-01-30T01:24:37.149477+00:00 app[worker.2]:   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-01-30T01:24:37.152710+00:00 app[worker.2]:   SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "batches" SET "progress" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "batches"."id" = $3  [["progress", "Verify Email In Progress"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-30 01:24:37.150315"], ["id", 55]]
```

I changed the bucket name for the post, but if I got to the url (which is putting to the logs), it downloads the CSV from aws - so I know the link is correct (and the fact that there are no errors). It seems to be `CSV`

I've been researching for hours - hopefully some fresh eyes will see the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The file is not accessible by your script, it's requires authorization.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes across this issue, I believe the issue is that in the worker, it is receiving a string, where as in the Rails controller it understood it's a URL and needed to sent through a csv... I'm not sure why it didn't throw an error though.

This is my working code:

```
class BatchWorker
   include Sidekiq::Worker
   require 'open-uri'
   require 'net/https'
   require 'csv'

  def perform(service_id, batch_id, current_user_id, file)
    batch = Batch.find(batch_id)

    escaped_link = URI.escape(file) 
    file = URI.parse(escaped_link)
    puts Net::HTTP.get(file)

    CSV.parse(Net::HTTP.get(file), :headers => true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
      puts 'CSV is open'
      puts row
      if row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?)
      else
        @datum = Datum.new
        @datum.attributes = row.to_hash.reject{|k,v| !@datum.attributes.keys.member?(k.to_s) }
        @datum.user_id = current_user_id
        @datum.batch_id = batch_id
        @datum.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```